# Starting a new process from python script and then killing it from the same script

Tags: python, windows, exe

I have looked at python's `subprocess` and `os` modules but have not been able to find a concrete example. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
os.system(r"someprocess.exe")
time.sleep(10)
os.system(r"TASKKILL /F /IM someprocess.exe")
```

Currently after running the first line, the shell runs the process within it, and does not move forward. On the other hand, I want it to spawn a new process independent of this python shell, go to sleep, and then kill it after sometime. I am on a windows machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use subprocess.

```
import subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(['notepad.exe'])
time.sleep(10)
p.kill()
```